# How to enable autofill for textarea street address?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, autocomplete, textarea

I have a form that includes a street address, city, state, and zip. It autocompletes for text inputs, but if I change the street address to a textarea it no longer autocompletes and the user has to type the entire street address.

```
// autocomplete works on the first character
<input type="text" name="address" autoComplete="shipping street-address" placeholder="Street address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleAddressChange} />

// does not autocomplete at all
<textarea name="address" autoComplete="shipping street-address" placeholder="Street address" value={this.state.address} onChange={this.handleAddressChange} />
```

The entire change is `input type="text"` vs `textarea`. Is there a way to enable autocomplete for the textarea too, or is there a reason it's not working specific to the React framework?

Comment: check this library. https://github.com/webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete or this codepen: https://codepen.io/jukben/pen/bYZqvR